# R: Define a matrix which general term is vectors product

Tags: r, matrix, vector, product

I would like to define a matrix (M) from two vectors products (v1 & v2).
What I mean is that

```
M(i, j) = v1(i) * v(j)
```

I know I could write a `for` loop but the matrix is bound to be big (400x400) so I am looking for a way to do that in the fastest way possible.

Bonus: In fact my two vectors are flattened matrices so if there's a way to do what I want to without flattening them, that would be perfect. (It sounds kind of like an Hadamard product but with all possible combinations between the two matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use outer

```
outer(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer works perfectly but I happened to find something that better suits that specific need : Kronecker product allows me to do just what I want AND keep everything under their matrices forms.

[Kronecker product's wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

```
M <- Mat1 %x% Mat2
```